# Show that $K:=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \lvert z\rvert =1\right\}$ is a topological group.

Tags: general-topology

> > As the title already says I have to show that
> >     $$
> > K:=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \lvert z\rvert =1\right\}
> > $$
> >     is a topological group.

First of all, $K$ is a group concerning the multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$; I think I do not have to show this here.

What is more interesting is to show that
$$
M\colon K\times K\to K, (a,b)\mapsto ab
$$ 
and
$$
I\colon K\to K, a\mapsto a^{-1}
$$
are continious, whereat on $K$ one considers the induced topology
$$
\mathcal{T}_K:=\left\{K\cap O: O\in\mathcal{O}\right\},
$$
where $\mathcal{O}$ is the natural topology on $\mathbb{C}$, and on $K\times K$ one considers the produt topology $\mathcal{T}_K\times\mathcal{T}_K$.

To do so, I need a little bit help, please.

First I have to show that $M$ is continious. To do so, I think I have to take a $A\in\mathcal{T}_K$ and have to show that
$$
M^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{T}_K\times\mathcal{T}_K.
$$
If yes, how can I show that?

If there is an easier way: Which is it?

Comment: Let $a=\exp i\theta$ and let $b=\exp i\theta'$ and recall that $ab=\exp i(\theta+\theta')$. You might find this easier to work with.

Comment: You can show that the multiplication on $\mathbb{C}$ is continuous.

Comment: Do I have to show this with the topological definition of continuity, i.e. taking an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and show that it's preimage is in the product topology on $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

1. The map $m:\Bbb C\times\Bbb C\rightarrow\Bbb C$ given by $m(w,z)=wz$ is certainly continuous (it's a polynomial!). What happens to a continuous map when you restrict it to a subspace with the induced topology?
2. Same thing with the inverse which on $K$ is the restriction of the map $i:\Bbb C^\times\rightarrow\Bbb C^\times$ given by $i(z)=1/z$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a topological group and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup, then it might be easier to show that the exponential map $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to K$ given by $f(x)=\exp 2\pi x$ is a continuous homomorphism with kernel equal to $\mathbb{Z}$. It's a standard result that if $G$ is a topological group and $H$ is a normal subgroup, then $G/H$ with the quotient topology is a topological group.